# javascript funcion replace

Tags: javascript, function, str-replace

¿De la siguiente función como sustituyo los espacios en blanco por guiones?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Ej funciones</title>
</head> 
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">


var texto=prompt ("Introduce el texto");

function espaciosEnBlanco() {
var sustituye=texto.split(" ");
var operacion=texto.replace(sustituye, "-");

alert(operacion);

}

espaciosEnBlanco();



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

No necesitas el `split`.  Solo con `replace` funciona asi:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Ej funciones</title>
</head> 
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var texto=prompt ("Introduce el texto");

function espaciosEnBlanco() {
  var operacion=texto.replace(/\s/g, "-");

  alert(operacion);

}

espaciosEnBlanco();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Iba a responder cuando he visto esta respuesta, así que prefiero *arreglarla*: si usas un string en lugar de una *regex* sólo se reemplaza la primera ocurrencia

Comment: ¿Y con un bucle como podría expresarlo? en vez de usar el regex

Comment: Bueno, si quieres explorar varios métodos, pondré una respuesta, aunque el método aquí expuesto me parece la solución más limpia

Answer (score 3):

Hay varias maneras de hacer lo mismo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Ej funciones</title>
</head> 
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var texto = prompt ("Introduce el texto");

function espaciosEnBlanco1() {
  var operacion=texto.replace(/\s/g, '-');

  console.log(operacion);

}
function espaciosEnBlanco2() {
  var operacion=texto.split(' ').join('-');

  console.log(operacion);

}

function espaciosEnBlanco3() {
  let operacion=texto;
  while(operacion.indexOf(' ') >-1) {
    operacion=operacion.replace(' ','-');
  }

  console.log(operacion);

}

espaciosEnBlanco1();
espaciosEnBlanco2();
espaciosEnBlanco3();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```